# doubango 1.0 and 2.0 compiling error on centos64

Tags: build, makefile

I am trying to compile doubango framework version 1.0 and got compile error. After upgrading to release 2.0 I got the same compile error.

```
src/codecs/vpx/tdav_codec_vp8.c:265: error: for each function it appears in.)
src/codecs/vpx/tdav_codec_vp8.c: In function âtdav_codec_vp8_open_encoderâ:
src/codecs/vpx/tdav_codec_vp8.c:675: warning: passing argument 1 of âvpx_codec_enc_config_defaultâ makes pointer from integer without a cast
/usr/include/vpx/vpx_encoder.h:609: note: expected âconst struct vpx_codec_iface *â but argument is of type âintâ
src/codecs/vpx/tdav_codec_vp8.c:720: warning: passing argument 2 of âvpx_codec_enc_init_verâ makes pointer from integer without a cast
/usr/include/vpx/vpx_encoder.h:575: note: expected âconst struct vpx_codec_iface *â but argument is of type âintâ
src/codecs/vpx/tdav_codec_vp8.c: In function âtdav_codec_vp8_open_decoderâ:
src/codecs/vpx/tdav_codec_vp8.c:774: warning: passing argument 2 of âvpx_codec_dec_init_verâ makes pointer from integer without a cast
/usr/include/vpx/vpx_decoder.h:121: note: expected âconst struct vpx_codec_iface *â but argument is of type âintâ
make[2]: *** [libtinyDAV_la-tdav_codec_vp8.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/telepresence/doubango-read-only/branches/2.0/doubango/tinyDAV'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/telepresence/doubango-read-only/branches/2.0/doubango'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Please advise, is there patch or modification on `doubango/tinyDAV/src/codecs/vpx/tdav_codec_vp8.c` or any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: If the configuration worked correctly, there is a bug in the code, or several bugs in the code.  Since Doubango 1.0 is deprecated, you should only bother with using Doubango 2.0 unless you are already using 1.0 (but even then, you should be upgrading).

Comment: I already tried with Doubango 2.0 but still same error that means lib vpx still buggy. I tried to compile without lib-vpx and it is works  ./autogen.sh && ./configure --with-speexdsp --with-ffmpeg --without-vpx - Please advice what is the impact if compiled withpout VPX ?

Comment: Succinctly: no idea. I'm unfamiliar with the software. I downloaded the source from the web site and tried to compile it, and ran into different problems, probably because I'm building on a Mac and not on Centos. They were unrelated to what you're seeing. I recommend joining their mailing lists and searching their archives. You could reasonably try '--without-vpx' and see whether it works well enough for you. You should check whether the problem has been reported before and if not, you should report it.